# Start java program into cycle with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nohup

I have some problems with nohup scripts. Try to start:

```
for i in `seq 1 2`; do "/usr/bin/nohup java -cp JavaProg.jar Sintetic.WriteBigFiles /store/file$i.lob &"; done;
```

Get error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/nohup java -cp JavaProg.jar Sintetic.WriteBigFiles /store/file1.lob &: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/nohup java -cp JavaProg.jar Sintetic.WriteBigFiles /store/file2.lob &: No such file or directory
```

In case of:

```
/usr/bin/nohup java -cp JavaProg.jar Sintetic.WriteBigFiles /store/file1.lob &
```

Everything is Ok.

Could anybody know some workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for i in `seq 1 2`; do /usr/bin/nohup java -cp JavaProg.jar Sintetic.WriteBigFiles /store/file$i.lob & ; done;
```

Comment: I try to do this: [root@cdh ~]# for i in seq 1 2; do /usr/bin/nohup java -cp JavaProg.jar Sintetic.WriteBigFiles /store/file$i.lob &; done and got: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'